Upper bound on number of cubes in a large cube in the intersection graph of unit cubes
Let $G$ be a connected intersection graph of $n$ unit cubes in $\mathbb R^d$, i.e., the vertices of $G$ are unit cubes of the form $[a_1,a_1+1]\times \cdots \times [a_d,a_d+1]$, where $a_i \in \mathbb R$, and there is an edge between two vertices if the corresponding cubes intersect. Assume that the maximum degree is $\Delta \ge 2$. Consider a larger cube (with sides parallel to the axes) of length $L$ anywhere in $\mathbb R^d$.
Question: Is there a nice upper bound on the number of unit cubes, associated with vertices of $G$, inside this larger cube?
An obvious upper bound is $n$, the total number of vertices, but I was wondering if there is a better bound that depends only on $L$ and $\Delta$ (and perhaps also on $d$).

I suspect the optimal arrangement is to just have $k$ stacks of $\Delta$ cubes, in exactly the same place, except with two in each stack shifted slightly to meet the connectedness criterion. E.g. this can pack $8\Delta$ cubes into a cube with $L=2+\varepsilon$

@ZoeAllen If I understand you correctly, the upper bound is like $L^d \Delta$ (assuming $L$ is slightly larger than an integer)?

It would be like $\Delta L^d$, which is the obvious bound you get from the volumes and the maximum amount of overlap

I have a proof for $d=1$, if that's of interest

Thanks, I think I know how to prove it for $d=1$ too.

Let $k=\lceil L \rceil -1$. Make a grid of $k^d$ dots inside the big cube, spaced with unit spacing, such that every unit cube has to intersect at least one of the points (as they are closed). All the cubes intersecting one of these dots intersect each other, so there can be at most $\Delta+1$ cubes intersecting a dot. But if $\Delta+1$ cubes intersect a dot, they all have maximal degree, so can't have an edge connecting them to the rest of the graph, hence for $k>1$ there can be at most $\Delta$ cubes intersecting a dot.
We can now construct such an arrangement of cubes, to prove the bound is attainable.
Think of a very small $\varepsilon$. Now make a grid of points with $1+\varepsilon$ spacing. Place $\Delta-2$ cubes starting at each vertex- none of these stacks of cubes will overlap other stacks. Now choose a Hamiltonian path between these stacks (where each stack has an edge only to the stacks directly next to it, no diagonals). For each edge in this path, we add two cubes, one to each stack, which are shifted slightly to be overlapping with each other, but not with each others' stacks*. This ensures the graph is connected. This adds two unit cubes to each stack, to reach our bound of $\Delta k^d$, except for the ends of our path, so add an extra cube to each of those. For a small enough $\varepsilon$, $k+(k-1)\varepsilon \le L$ so this can always fit inside our large cube. This completes our construction and our proof.
*e.g. if our cubes stacks are $[0,1]^d$ and $[0,1]^d+(1+\varepsilon)e_1$ where $e_1=(1,0,0,\dots)$, we could add extra cubes $[0,1]^d+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}e_1$ and $[0,1]^d+(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{2})e_1$. The extra region that this fills in is only in the convex hull of that pair of adjacent stacks, no others, so it will not intersect any of the other extra regions that we fill in. This ensures we aren't adding any unwanted edges.

Awesome! That makes sense. Thanks!
